# Painting over bathroom tiles?

Tags: bathroom, paint, ceramic-tile

Saw this in an Airbnb apartment I stayed in:

[image: Painted over tiles]

So the tiles including the joins where simply painted over with some very thick glossy paint.

Let's say there is some mold underneath, would it be safe? The assumption being that he mold below simply dies off?

Comment: If they painted it properly, they would have prepped the surface.

Comment: Mold, schmold. It sure is ugly. But I guess if you're too lazy to regrout, you can have an ugly mess by slapping some paint on...

Comment: @RohitGupta How would you prep it in case of your average ceramic tiles?

Answer (score 3):

Fungal (mold) spores are everywhere. You are breathing them right now, and mold is trying to grow inside of you, constantly. Your immune system is taking care of the problem for you. Bathroom mold is a cosmetic problem, not a health problem.

Mold becomes a problem in circumstances such as in the aftermath of floods, because the whole house stays dark and wet, and it then grows everywhere and overwhelms your senses with the amount of spores, causing allergies, etc. How much mold is too much depends on the individual. I am very sensitive to it, and can only enter basements with a mask.

If there is mold underneath the paint is of no concern, because those spores cannot become airborne.